# iPhone 6 touch screen have problems

Tags: iphone

I have iPhone6 and it is working perfectly till now. The iOS version is IOS9.3.2

Recently I am facing the below problems

It doesn't recognize my touch strokes some times. It happens twice or thrice in a day. But when I lock explicitly by side button and then I unlock it used to work fine.

But today the problem become worse. The touch strokes working in correctly. Below are the problems
 - If I touch one thing another thing other thing is happening. Example is if I touch Phone app. It is opening browser and automatically types some letters in the address bar.

- While typing problem is worse. If i try to enter password for AppleId/Wifi. If I type 's' it is typing 'oijh', something like that.
- If I open phone app, it automatically calls some number and some times dropping the call.
- If I open mail, it automatically opens some folders and some mail moving those into some other folder.

I have erased all settings and content. But still the same issue.

I don't understand what is happening my iPhone6. is it Virus got attacked? How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had similar issues with my iPhone 6+. It's very disruptive and makes it very difficult to complete even simple tasks. You may have a defective digitizer or loose connector. Has your phone recently experienced any drops or hard impacts? Your best bet is to visit an Apple store and have the screen/digitizer replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that issue before. You will need to take your device to Apple or an Authorised Service Provider for service.
See https://locate.apple.com to find your nearest service location.

They will most likely replace either the whole Display part or the device itself.